# Spring Batch Split Processor

Tags: java, spring-batch, batch-processing

I need to apply different processor chains based on record properties, producing different record types.

```
                             /--> processor A --> writer A
reader --> split processor --|
                             \--> processor B --> writer B
```

So that processing vary by read items:

```
A record (read) -> (split processor) -> (processor A) -> (writer A)
B record (read) -> (split processor) -> (processor B) -> (writer B)
```

This can be made using multiple `ItemProcessListener`s and writing filtering logic in `afterProcess()`.

Looking for a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor.html) is what you are looking for (what you call `split processor`). This item processor uses a `Classifier` to classify items and pass them to delegate processors accordingly.

To achieve the pattern you described, you would need to combine this processor with a similar item writer: the [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html).